# python extract data from sql file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract the text from.

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (176447, 'Miguel', 'Lucas', 'MLUCAS3', 'lukszmb2011@hotmail.com', 'lukszmb2011@hotmail.com', '{\"_token\":\"3P8y4r34uPPRMFPJZl8Axq2WgKNHJfPZdMw79PRV\",\"payable_vouchers\":[null],\"user_leg\":\"default\",\"payment\":\"free\",\"sponsor\":\"611d7018d607b\",\"firstname\":\"Miguel\",\"lastname\":\"Lucas\",\"country\":\"EC\",\"state\":\"P\",\"zip\":\"170102\",\"address\":\"Caupicho Bellavista calle EI8 lote 1458\",\"city\":\"Quito\",\"gender\":\"m\",\"phone\":\"0989267630\",\"email\":\"lukszmb2011@hotmail.com\",\"wechat\":null,\"passport\":\"1723806822\",\"transaction_pass\":\"5BxLkKhYPLF\",\"username\":\"MLUCAS3\",\"password\":\"MLucas3#\",\"confirm_password\":\"MLucas3#\",\"check\":null,\"reg_type\":null,\"cpf\":null,\"package\":15,\"location\":null,\"reg_by\":\"Free\",\"leg\":\"default\",\"google2fa_secret\":\"5EWTTF3LVQ7CI37V\"}', '$2y$10$K1eAyJRgYmH5otQtdE6dU.W7NDtiAag6jwBKliWS.CORd..7UgTjK', 'default', '613166ea33f0a', 'L', 'eyJpdiI6IllBRjB0QXQrQUlTekVyKzdaSC9zOUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNmFNTGN3T2ljZmFSM3phU0ZNRXBLUT09IiwibWFjIjoiMzY0NTg5NDI0MzQxMTk3YTZhNjMxZDI4YmM0N2IzYjE3NTJhMGY0NTAyMjdiNzQ0MjBjMTkwMzYxNGM3NzIzNiJ9', '5BxLkKhYPLF', 1, 1, 'Free', 'yes', 'yes', '0', NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, NULL, 'eyJpdiI6IlYyVjVvVm16TjlaRGVRZHdhWllsVWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidVlQY1luQnBDSzNxN25LVC82bFZpRXgySEVDS1dyalFKWEQ2ZjFiVlVSaz0iLCJtYWMiOiJkZjU2M2EzN2NjZGZlNDljNjg4MzY0ODEwZTY2MTY1ZTE2NzBmMDNiZTIzOTFhNzRlMThlNDNlMWNjNTAxMGI3In0=', '', 0, 1, 0, 0, NULL, '2021-09-03 00:06:02', '2021-09-03 02:35:19', NULL, NULL, 0, '0');
```

and i want extract only

```
"email\":\"lukszmb2011@hotmail.com and "password\":\"MLucas3#\"
```

format like.

```
email:password
```

Answer (score 0):

If curly braces occurs only once in your string, you can extract that and convert to json:

```
>>> import json

>>> mydict = json.loads("{" + (s.split('{')[1]).split("}")[0] + "}")

>>> mydict['email']
'lukszmb2011@hotmail.com'
>>> mydict['password']
'MLucas3#'
```

Formatting that to your expected format should be easy